# Alternatives to Google Places API

Tags: api, google-places-api

What are alternatives to 'Google Places API' ? No matter if there is any paid API Service.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033422/alternative-to-google-place-api, which came later, but is more detailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced this issue when was searching a way to implement the autocompletion field for user input location field in iOS app. One of the best example of how it works I think was made in Apple's native Weather App. There are more search results on "add new location screen)" than gives any other service I have tried:
 - Google Place API (main alternative)
 - Yelp
 - Foursquare
 - some others.

Unfortunately Weather uses https requests: (https://gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com). :(
It may seems that there is no solution to retrieve this data. But as turned out Apple ain't use their own service for location determination.

I checked Maps app and tried `CLGeocoder` class with it's - `-(void)geocodeAddressString:(NSString *)addressString completionHandler:` (persists only in iOS)

Last one was useless, finding only one result while Google gave about 5's (for word 'Mosc' as a part of Moscow)

**Solution:** Apple discarded Yahoo as a weather provider and chose [TWC](http://www.weather.com) ([prooflink](http://www.macrumors.com/2014/06/03/ios-8-new-weather-app/)).
So our case is not to collect weather conditions but rather get the locations, what they also provide!

To be exact let's compare several services:
[image]
(top image - google maps that exploit Place API, bottom - TWC, that Apple uses)

**Pros (TWC):**
 - Search can be made by city (zip,airport etc.)
 - More results are found (if even set max. radius for google query - 50 000, it would not find a lot)
 - Supports API with Autocomplete options
 - Well-suited for autocompletion purpose, contains all the basic fields
 JSON looks like the below:

```
{
     "name":"Moscu, CUN, COLOMBIA",
      "key":"COXX8971:1:CO",
    "locId":"COXX8971",
  "locType":1,
   "cityNm":"Moscu",
  "cntryCd":"CO",
 "_country":"COLOMBIA",
     "stCd":"CUN",
     "stNm":"Cundinamarca",
  "bigCity":false
},
```

**Cons:**
- Much less powerful than Google if you need a geocoding options or query for places. 
- Handles requests slower than google does

Answer (score 3):

You can try openStreetMap an open source maps proyect http://www.osmfoundation.org/wiki/Main_Page

also you can find information of how it works http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStreetMap

is a really good alternative and it is made by comunity for comunity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why every vote, but the first one got down votes. Seems sketchy...

Anyways, OpenStreetMaps could be a possible choice, but from my experience they don't have much data about businesses compared to other services.

Bing Maps is another good choice. Its what Facebook uses for their 'places' pages and it seems to have a pretty good amount of data.

Foursquare is definitely a solid choice... if you stay in the US. Their rates are pretty competitive compared to Google's, but you do have to deal with duplicate entries and some not completely filled out information.

I research Yelp's API some time ago, so I don't remember how good they are. I just remembered that they didn't offer as good of a service compared to Bing, Google, and Foursquare.

All of those are paid services, except for OpenStreetMaps. If I remember correctly, Google had the best overall data for businesses, but Foursquare takes the cake when it comes to pricing. In the end, it's all up to what you specifically need since they are all pretty good choices.

Comment: I am truly not sure why [David's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29726137/3672811) answer was selected as the best answer. OP asked for an alternative to the Places API, which from my understanding, means they are looking for information on local businesses. Something the weather channel API doesn't provide, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

ok,as I know,if you want to use a geo api,it must be a big company.so,what about bing map,or chinese biggest Internet company baidu's baidu'map?

Comment: big company ? I need to display information about nearest famous places, local events etc etc.

Comment: I think bing map is a good choice,you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

They are:

- Yelp.com
- Foursquare.com

Both of them has their own APIs which can be used by anyone.

Comment: Talking about Foursquare Places API, here's how to do it - https://getbutterfly.com/how-to-populate-openstreetmap-with-foursquare-venues-amenities/

Answer (score 0):

Try Foursquare.com, its free and usage limits are very considerable. 5000 requests per hour.

Comment: Talking about Foursquare Places API, here's how to do it - https://getbutterfly.com/how-to-populate-openstreetmap-with-foursquare-venues-amenities/