# Alternative to google place api?

Tags: ios, openstreetmap, google-places-api

I'm developing an iphone app that is using Google Place API. As far as I know, Google allows 1000 queries per 24 hour for this Place API, and 100,000 queries per 24 hour if the account is verified with a credit card. Exceeding 100,000 queries per 24 hour will incur extra charge.

I'm asking if there is any another option rather than using this Google Place API? Which can support unlimited queries. If there is, what is the charge?

I've heard of openStreetMap is free. But i'm not sure if there is any party providing the Place API base on this OpenStreetMap, and the limit.

Thanks

Comment: you can use bing api for maps in iphone http://ibing.codeplex.com/

Comment: also http://www.vicchi.org/2011/09/05/farewell-ovi-maps-hello-nokia-maps-on-ios-and-android-too/

Comment: yeah i'm look at Bing. Is there any other option? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The Google Places API will not charge you for exceeding your quota, even with billing enabled you will simple receive `"status": "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"`

As per the [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#usage_limits) section of the Places API Documentation:

> - Users with an API key are allowed 1 000 requests per 24 hour period.
> - Users who have also verified their identity through the APIs console are allowed 100 000 requests per 24 hour period. A credit card
>     is required for verification, by enabling billing in the console.
>     **Your card will not be charged for use of the Places API**.

If you would like to request more than 100 000 queries per day, log in and fill out the [Places API Quota Uplift Request form](http://places-quota-uplifts.appspot.com/) with your application details, we will then review your application to ensure it meets our [Terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) and [Requirements](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#Limits) after which we will contact you shortly with the result of your request.

Comment: I have a question, if Google doesn't approve our request, what will happen? And if Google is charging, how does it cost?

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108053/google-place-api-pricing-and-queries-uplift-request).

Answer (score 6):

There are some alternatives:

- [Yelp.com](http://yelp.com)
- [Foursquare.com](http://foursquare.com) (5000 requests per hour, 120 000 per day, uses OpenStreetMap)

Yelp.com has more strict API usage limits, Foursquare.com has less restrictive API usage limits, they even allow response caching for some time to improve application performance.

Comment: Yelp.Com updated their policies the last years. 25k requests free per day. See https://www.yelp.com/developers/faq. You can apply for more. For free.