# Google place API pricing and queries uplift request

Tags: google-places-api

Regarding the usage of Google Place API, Google allows 1000 queries per 24 hour for this Place API, and 100,000 queries per 24 hour if the account is verified with a credit card. Exceeding 100,000 queries per 24 hour, we can write to Google to request for an uplift.

Does anyone have any experience with lifting the limits for the queries of Place API?
And if you didn't get approved, what is the Google's pricing model for exceeding usage of the queries?

Thanks

Comment: This may be better suited to http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Non technical questions about the Places API should be posted on the [Places API Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/google-places-api).

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/policies#usage_limits

Answer (score 5):

There is currently no pricing model for Places API as it is a free service. If you exceed your usage you will simply receive `"status": "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"` in response to any subsequent Places API requests. Even if billing is enabled, **you will not be charged for the use of the Places API**.

If you apply for a [Places API Quota Uplift](http://places-quota-uplifts.appspot.com/), as long as your application meets the Google Maps [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) and Places API [Requirements](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#Limits), you should receive an uplift in quota.